# How to keep Count Tool marks permanent on layer after trim/crop/move layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

1. I edit image, add marks with count tool (1, 2), because I need to mark specific point on layer and later I will work with the coordinates of this point.
2. I apply trim/crop tool on layer.

Result: layer moved to left side but marks stayed on original position and off layer.

Goal: I need to keep marks permanent on the layer. Still keep marks on layer when layer is moved/trim/crop.. Is there solution for this? Or another options to mark points on layer?

Thank You!
[image]

Comment: This looks like a potential bug, and you will need to contact Adobe about it. Nothing we can do about it.  Of course, you could always crop it before you use the Count Tool, or just don't crop it obviously.